# Counting how many numbers are in a string

Tags: python, python-2.7, count, string-length

Below should be a fairly easy counting/length need however I can't work out how to get it working...

#### Example code

```
tl1 = "2, 5, 11"
tl2 = "2, 5, 11, 29, 48, 1, 492, 2993, 91, 8, 8, 3"
tl3 = "9382938238"
print len(tl1)
print len(tl2)
print len(tl3)
```

#### What it returns:

```
8
43
1
```

#### What it should (for me) return::

```
3
12
1
```

Any idea how to achieve the return that I wanted?

Thanks
- Hyflex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> > Your problem is that in a `string`, spaces and characters count in the length.

So, the length of this variable, which is a string:

```
string = '123 abc'
```

is 7, because the space counts.

Now, to get the result you are looking for, you need to change the string to a list, which is a group of comma separated values. Note that we don't name our list 'list', because `list()` is a function in python:

```
lst = ['2','5','11']
```

Now, when we check the length of our list:

```
>>> print len(lst)
3
```

And we get '3' as the result

To get your string to look like the list above:

```
>>> tl1 = "2, 5, 11"
>>> print tl1.split(',')
['2','5','11']
```

Then you could check the length using `len()`

Answer (score 2):

The length of string is the number of characters in the string.

Use [`str.split`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes#str.split) with comma(`','`):

```
>>> tl1 = "2, 5, 11"
>>> tl2 = "2, 5, 11, 29, 48, 1, 492, 2993, 91, 8, 8, 3"
>>> tl3 = "9382938238"

>>> tl1.split(',')
['2', ' 5', ' 11']

>>> len(tl1.split(','))
3
>>> len(tl2.split(','))
12
>>> len(tl3.split(','))
1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this pretty easily with regular expressions:

```
>> import re
>> result = re.split(r'\D+', '1, 2, 35')
>> result
   ['1', '2', '35']
>> len(result)
   3
```

If you need to support floating point numbers or something else, it is a bit more complicated, but regular expressions are still the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

If all of your strings are like that, then you can simply use the [`.split`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes#str.split) method of a string:

```
>>> tl1 = "2, 5, 11"
>>> tl2 = "2, 5, 11, 29, 48, 1, 492, 2993, 91, 8, 8, 3"
>>> tl3 = "9382938238"
>>> len(tl1.split())
3
>>> len(tl2.split())
12
>>> len(tl3.split())
1
>>>
```

`.split` defaults to split on whitespace characters.  You could also split on `,` if there is a chance that there could be more than 1 space between the numbers.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way:

```
tl1 = "2, 5, 11"
tl2 = "2, 5, 11, 29, 48, 1, 492, 2993, 91, 8, 8, 3"
tl3 = "9382938238"

for t in (tl1,tl2,tl3):
    print len([x for x in t.split(',') if x.strip().isdigit()])
```

Prints:

```
3
12
1
```

The advantage is this counts the actual integers, not just the number of split items:

```
>>> tl4 = '1, 2, a, b, 3, 44'   # 4 numbers, 5 commas, 6 items (numbers and letters)
>>> len(tl4.split(','))
6                               # that numbers and letters...
>>> len([x for x in tl4.split(',') if x.strip().isdigit()])
4                               # integer fields only
```